# How to pass data between 2 activities and display it in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I try to pass SQLite data between 2 activities and display it in a recyclerview. I run the app, but it stops. How can I make this work?

The activities:

1.SQLite Database

DatabseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tasksManager";
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";
private static final String KEY_TASK_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_TASK_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_TASK_DATE = "date";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "(" + KEY_TASK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            KEY_TASK_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TASK_DATE + " TEXT" + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tasks" + TABLE_TASKS);
onCreate(db);
}

public void addTask(Task task){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_TASK_NAME, task.getTaskName());
    values.put(KEY_TASK_DATE, task.getTaskDate());

    db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
    db.close();

}

public ArrayList<Task> getAllTasks(){
    String[] columns = {
            KEY_TASK_ID,
            KEY_TASK_NAME,
            KEY_TASK_DATE};
    ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TASKS,
            columns,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
         do {
             Task task = new Task(
                     parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                     cursor.getString(1),
                     cursor.getString(2));
            taskList.add(task);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return taskList;
}
```

2.The activity from where I want to get the data

AddTaskActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView addNewTask, setStartTime, setEndTime;
EditText addTaskName;
TimePicker timePicker1, timePicker2;
int hour1, minute1;
int hour2, minute2;
String theNewTask;
Button addTaskButton;
TasksListActivity tla;
DatabaseHandler dth;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_task);
    dth = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    addNewTask = findViewById(R.id.addNewTask);
    setStartTime = findViewById(R.id.setStartTime);
    setEndTime = findViewById(R.id.setEndTime);
    addTaskName = findViewById(R.id.addTaskName);
    timePicker1 = findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    timePicker2 = findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
    addTaskButton = findViewById(R.id.addTaskButton);


    addTaskButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String name = addTaskName.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddTaskActivity.this, TasksListActivity.class);

                    Task task = new Task();
                    task.setTaskName(name);
                    task.setTaskDate("date");

                    dth.addTask(task);

                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );

}
```

}

3.The activity where I want to display the data

TasksListActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TasksListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TaskAdapter taskAdapter;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<Task> tasksList;
DatabaseHandler dth;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks_list);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.taskListItem:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(TasksListActivity.this, TasksListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;
                case R.id.addTasks:
                    Intent intent5 = new Intent(TasksListActivity.this, AddTaskActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent5);
                    break;
                case R.id.noteListItem:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(TasksListActivity.this, NotesListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    tasksList = new ArrayList<>();
    taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(tasksList, TasksListActivity.this);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    dth = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(taskAdapter);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = bundle.getString("name");
    getDataFromSQLiteDatabase();
}

    private void getDataFromSQLiteDatabase(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
                tasksList.clear();
                tasksList.addAll(dth.getAllTasks());

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }.execute();

}


}
```

Edit: I changed Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                String name = bundle.getString("name");

to
                String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

and Logcat shows this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.example.android.todolistapp.DatabaseHandler.getAllTasks(DatabaseHandler.java:182)
    at com.example.android.todolistapp.TasksListActivity$2.doInBackground(TasksListActivity.java:74)
    at com.example.android.todolistapp.TasksListActivity$2.doInBackground(TasksListActivity.java:70)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = bundle.getString("name");
```

with this 
`String name =getIntent().getStringExtras("name")`

Answer (score 0):

## The Issue

Your issue is that you are not checking if the Cursor has any rows and that there are not any.

More specifically a Cursor returned from any SQLiteDatabase method that returns a Cursor will not be null. Checking to see if the Cursor is null is useless as the Cursor will never be null.

Therefore, the **moveToFirst** cannot then move to a row and returns false. The false is not checked for and hence you get the message `Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`. **Index 0** is the column (so you are requesting data from the column who's offset is 0, which is fine). **Size of 0** is saying that **the number of rows in the Cursor is 0** so there is no data to be retrieved.

## The Fix

So you need to remove that line and then do a proper check to see if you can move to a row. Fortunately the move methods (moveToFirst, moveToNext .....) return a boolean that indicates if the move was successful or not.

- An alternative would be to use the Cursor's getCount method, to see if there are any rows in the Cursor.

As such I'd suggest using :-

```
while (cursor.moveToNext() {
    Task task = new Task(
             parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
             cursor.getString(1),
             cursor.getString(2));
    taskList.add(task);
}
```

Instead of :-

```
if(cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
     do {
         Task task = new Task(
                 parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                 cursor.getString(1),
                 cursor.getString(2));
        taskList.add(task);
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext());

}
```

## Important

**However**, as the above failed with ......**a size of 0** and that you have no selection criteria then the **tasks** table is empty.